# Changeforgotten password page is blank, disabling customer.xml fixes?

Tags: magento-1.8, password-recovery

Clicking the password reset link sent in an email leads to the /customer/account/changeforgotten/ page, but it is blank.

Disabling the customer.xml file (renaming it rather) fixes the issue but I don't want to leave it disabled, nor do I want to have an unworking/outdated customer.xml file.

The below is my current code that leaves my login button intact (the replacement code further below does remove the login button), but keeps the changeforgotten page blank:

        Customer Forgot Password Form

```
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
        <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_forgotpassword>
```

I have tried adding the below, but it removes my login button and still leaves the changeforgotten page blank. 

    Reset a Password

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Besides disabling the customer.xml file, is there a fix? I'm running CE 1.8.1.0, and pretty new to Magento. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure this is in your customer.xml file. Pay attention to the change in customer_account_forgotpassword. Sounds like possibly and old theme issue after applying patch SUPEE 6788

```
<customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
    <label>Customer Forgot Password Form</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
        <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_forgotpassword>

<customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_changeforgotten>
```

Comment: same issue solved refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443503/supee-6788-and-password-reset-blank-page

Answer (score 1):

```
Find

<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_resetpassword>

And Paste

<customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_changeforgotten>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check that page http://www.tripleginteractive.com/blog/magento/magentos-forgot-reset-password-page-blank-fix/

the problem is on customer.xml , you need to add after *customer_account_forgotpassword*

Comment: Linking to an external site with no new infomation providedto the answer