# Login button disappeared + Password reset issue

Tags: magento-1.9, login, password

Total newbie here. My website's password reset link was pulling up a blank page. Googled and tried [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116149/changeforgotten-password-page-is-blank-disabling-customer-xml-fixes) but now my login button has disappeared. I reverted to the original code but the login button still won't come back. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance! Attaching code here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     meigeetheme_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 MeigeeTeam. (http://www.meigeeteam.com)
 */



Supported layout update handles (action):
- customer_account_index
- customer_address_index
- customer_address_view
- customer_account_login
- customer_account_logoutsuccess
- customer_account_create
- customer_account_forgotpassword
- customer_account_confirmation
- customer_account_edit

Supported layout update handles (special):
- default

-->
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position><liParams/><aParams>class="top-link-account"</aParams></action>
        </reference>
    </default>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
-->

    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position><liParams/><aParams>class="top-link-logout"</aParams></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged out
-->

    <customer_logged_out>
        <!---<reference name="right">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
        </reference>-->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position><liParams/><aParams>class="top-link-login"</aParams></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
    </customer_logged_out>

<!--
Layout for customer login page
-->

    <customer_account_login translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>

<!--
Layout for customer log out page
-->

    <customer_account_logoutsuccess translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Logout Success</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="customer_logout" template="customer/logout.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_logoutsuccess>

<!--
New customer registration
-->

    <customer_account_create translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Form Fields Before</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>

    <customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
        <label>Customer Forgot Password Form</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
            <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>

    <customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
        <label>Reset a Password</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_resetpassword>

    <customer_account_confirmation>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Send confirmation link</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="accountConfirmation" template="customer/form/confirmation.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_confirmation>

    <customer_account_edit translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Edit Form</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Edit Account Info</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/form_edit" name="customer_edit" template="customer/form/edit.phtml"/>
        </reference>

        <reference name="left">
          <action method="unsetChild"><name>left.permanent.callout</name></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>

<!--
Customer account pages, rendered for all tabs in dashboard
-->

    <customer_account translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
        <!--remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
        <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/-->
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

        <reference name="sidebar">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            </block>
            <!--<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>-->            
            <remove name="tags_popular"/>

        </reference>
    </customer_account>

<!--
Customer account home dashboard layout
-->

    <customer_account_index translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_hello" name="customer_account_dashboard_hello" as="hello" template="customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" />
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_dashboard_address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>

    </customer_account_index>

<!--
Customer account address book
-->

    <customer_address_index translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Address Book</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/address_book" name="address_book" template="customer/address/book.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_address_index>

<!--
Customer account address edit page
-->

    <customer_address_form translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Address Edit Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="customer/address_edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="customer/address/edit.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_address_form>

</layout>
```

Comment: Revert all code and remove var, public/static, generated folder and deploy check

Comment: This is Magento1, Pramod

Comment: Remove your var/cache folder after you revert all your code

Comment: Thank you all, but none of these worked unfortunately. Any other suggestions? Magento version is 1.9.2.4